# touch and scroll a ListView inside a ScrollView cause the ScrollView not rendered anymore

Tags: listview, react-native, scrollview

I have a ListView inside a ScrollView.
The listview can scroll vertically, and the scrollview can scroll horizontally.

The view hierarchy is like this: Top View --> ScrollView --> ListView.

When I touch and scroll the listview, the ScrollView's render function will not be called anymore. -The Top View's render function is called as expected, while it just don't update the ScrollView.

If I don't do the touch-and-scroll, then everything just goes fine.
And, after the touch-and-scroll, if I touch and scroll the ScrollView, then everything will go back well.

If feels like that the listview has got the focus after the touch-and-scroll, and things will not go well until it lose the focus.

Can you help? Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems the actual trigger action is a long press.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause.

I'm setting a flag in onResponderGrant of the ScrollView, and clearing the flag in its onResponderRelease.
And in the ScrollView's shouldComponentUpdate, the flag is checked.

When I do the touch-and-scroll in the ListView, only onResponderGrant of the ScrollView is called and there's no call of its onResponderRelease, so the flag is not cleared.

Why the onResponderRelease is not called may be a bug of ReactNative.